# Query with grouped results by column (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I've got a many to many relationship between `items`-`itemnames`-`languages`

The `itemnames` don't appear for every language.

I'd like to get a result with all the items only represented once, but be able to set the `languageId` to default to.

For example items 1,2,3 are defined in two languages, and item 4 and 5 have one language each, but the languages are different

```
[itemid][languageid][name]
1,       1,         item1
1,       2,         leItem1
2,       1,         item2
2,       2,         leItem2
3,       1,         item3
3,       2,         leItem3
4,       1,         item4
5,       2,         leItem5
```

I'd like to create a query that only gives me one of each `itemID`, but allow me to specify which language to *prefer*, so if I select a `languageID` of 2, my query would only return item names for that start with 'leItem' with the exception of item 4, which should still give me `item4`

Any ideas how to achieve this with a SELECT?

The theory (how I'm trying to get it to work), is that I create two queries, one for all where `languageID` matches x , and second where each item is represented (by group or distinct) and then merge the results.

---

sql for generating the table

```
-- Languages
CREATE TABLE [Languages] (
    [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [language] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    [languagecode] NVARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);


-- Items
CREATE TABLE [Items] (
    [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [ImageId] INT ,
    [lastupdate] DATETIME,
    [isactive] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TRUE'
);

-- ItemNames
CREATE TABLE [ItemNames] (
    [itemId] INT NOT NULL ,
    [languageId] INT NOT NULL ,
    [name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (itemId) REFERENCES Items(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (languageId) REFERENCES Languages(id),
    PRIMARY KEY ([itemId],[languageId])
);
```

Comment: What are the actual tables involved (without the view). Also, as mentioned below what should happen if there are multiple non-preferred languages?

Comment: those are the actual tables, if there are multiple it should get the one with the lowest id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a `CASE` statement. Basically the idea is to determine if the preferred language exists and return `null` if it does *not*. That way you can utilize `ISNULL` to returned the preferred language (when it is populated) otherwise return the minimum language ID:

```
// replace @preferred with the preferred language id ie 2
SELECT  itn.ItemID, itn.LanguageID, itn.Name
FROM    ItemNames itn INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  itemID, 
                    // use preferred language if it exists
                    // otherwise, use the minimum languageID
                    ISNULL( MIN ( CASE WHEN LanguageID = @preferred THEN LanguageID ELSE NULL END ) 
                                , MIN (LanguageID) 
                          ) AS LanguageID
            FROM   ItemNames 
            GROUP BY itemID
        )
        sel ON sel.ItemID = itn.ItemID AND sel.LanguageID = itn.LanguageID
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve this with a subquery. This might not be the best way way of solving it, but I'll take a stab at it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  outer.itemid, 
  outer.languageid, 
  outer.name 
FROM 
  table AS outer
WHERE 
  outer.languageid = 2  
  OR NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM table AS inner WHERE languageid = 2 AND inner.itemid = outer.itemid)
```

The first where condition is to provide all the entries that belongs to languageid = 2, the second part of the where conditions return true only if there isn't an entry with languageid = 2 for the current item you're looking at.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Thanks David, I'm handling the first set of joins through a view anyway, so a subquery is inevitable. I guess the area I'm most interested in is what follow `WHEN` I'll give this a tinker

Comment: If a third language is introduced into the data set, say `4, 3, Foobar4`, this query will return two rows for item 4.

Comment: True, it's not very clear from the description how to handle a case like that. What happens if the preferred language does not exist but there are multiple non-preferred languages.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I'm handling it for now...

I've created a cffunction that loops through the query repeatedly. It works, and because I'm sub-querying, I think performance should be ok. Seems like using a database side query might  be too difficult for me.

```
<cffunction name="getLanguageUniqueEntries" output="no" returntype="query" >
    <cfargument name="q" Type="query" required="true">
    <cfargument name="languageId" Type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="uniqueColumn" Type="string" required="false" default="ID">

    <!---  Copy structure, assume table has an id column where no item matches -1 --->
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="newQ"> SELECT * FROM q WHERE #uniqueColumn# = -1 </cfquery>

    <!--- get list of unigue IDs --->
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="uniquePropertyIDs"> SELECT #uniqueColumn# FROM q GROUP BY #uniqueColumn# </cfquery>

    <!--- loop through unique IDs ---->
    <cfloop query="uniquePropertyIDs">
        <cfset colIdVal = uniquePropertyIDs[uniqueColumn][uniquePropertyIDs.CurrentRow]>

        <!--- find row in language --->
        <cfquery dbtype="query" name="currentLangQ" maxrows="1">
            SELECT * FROM q WHERE #uniqueColumn# = #colIdVal# AND LanguageID = #languageId#
        </cfquery>

        <cfif currentLangQ.recordcount NEQ 0>
            <!--- insert row --->
            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="newQ"> SELECT * FROM newQ UNION SELECT * FROM currentLangQ </cfquery>
        <cfelse>
            <!--- entry in language not found, get a default value --->
            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="anyLangQ" maxrows="1"> SELECT * FROM q WHERE #uniqueColumn# = #colIdVal# ORDER BY LanguageID</cfquery>

            <!--- insert row --->
            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="newQ"> SELECT * FROM newQ UNION SELECT * FROM anyLangQ</cfquery>
        </cfif>

    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn newQ>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I do not think you need to jump through such hoops for this :). If you post the ddl's of the tables involved, we could offer more specific advice.

Comment: Use management studio to generate the [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language#CREATE_statements).

Comment: .. or since it's only a few tables you could do it by hand. We just need to see the table structure ie column names and data types.

Comment: added the SQL to original post